# change how initial parenthesis is highlighted

Tags: highlighting, programming

I recently installed a programming package, "Haskell mode," and apparently I changed how "initial parenthesis highlighting" works. I'm used to a quick black/white box superimposed on the initial parenthesis. Now there is a solid colored box that lingers for a while. How do I change this back to the default behavior?

Comment: May be it enabled `show-paren-mode`. Try `(show-paren-mode -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original behaviour you describe sounds like `blink-matching-paren`:

> blink-matching-paren is a variable defined in `simple.el`.
>
> Non-nil means show matching open-paren when close-paren is inserted.
>   If t, highlight the paren.  If `jump', move cursor to its position.

The new behaviour you are seeing sounds like `show-paren-mode`. From the help for that function:

> Show Paren mode is a global minor mode.  When enabled, any
>   matching parenthesis is highlighted in `show-paren-style` after
>   `show-paren-delay` seconds of Emacs idle time.

As @nitishch commented, you can turn off `show-paren-mode` with `(show-paren-mode -1)`. You can customize the behaviour of `blink-matching-paren` via `M-x customize-variable blink-matching-paren`. You can customize `show-paren-mode` via `M-x customize-group paren-showing` - this allows you to set the delay before showing parens, and the faces (fonts) used to highlight them.